# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child when using map react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map through an array. However, I keep getting the following error:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child when using map react`

My `transactions` array has two objects in it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
{transactions &&
          transactions?.map((transact, index) => {
            console.log(transact.timestamp);
            return (
              <WalletTransactions
                key={index}
                username={transact.savedUser}
                date={transact.timestamp}
              />
            );
          })}
```

Here is the wallet transaction code:

```js
const fetchTransactions = () => {
    let transactions = [];
    db.collection("private")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("saved")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          transactions.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        });
        setTransactions(transactions);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTransactions();
  }, []);
```

Here is my wallet component:

```
function WalletTransactions({ username, date }) {
  return (
    <div className="wallet_transactions">
      <div className="wallet_transactionsLeft">
        <div className="dollar_container">
          <DollarSignFilledIcon />
        </div>
        <div className="transaction_text">
          <h4>Saved {username}'s link</h4>
          <p>{date}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="wallet_transactionsRight">
        <p>+5 points</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post WalletTransactions code?

Comment: @JoseRojas So what is the solution?

Comment: @JoseRojas Just updated!

Comment: The error is because you try to render an object as text

Comment: I meant post the code of the WalletTransactions component code

Comment: @JoseRojas Got it, so how do I render it properly?

Comment: @JoseRojas Just updated

Comment: Take a look at username prop in your wallet component, it might be an object and not a text the same to date

Comment: Just render with Json stringify then look at what's up